# Remove distinct values based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset I am trying to remove duplicate values on but need to retain the rows where a condition is met. It looks like,

```
col1 col2
a    NA
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    1
d    2
```

If I just run the normal distinct functions I retain just the first value/row of the duplicates

```
col1 col2
a    NA
b    1
c    1
d    1
```

BUT - I need to retain

```
col1 col2
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    1
```

I have tried

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>%
  top_n(1, col2)
```

But it seems to be removing extra rows within a larger dataset that does not represent duplicates from col1. It is somehow running it's own condition on col2 and removing extra beyond the duplicates.

In my real example col1 are serial #'s and col2 are dates. I am trying to remove NA's from col2 while also trying to preserve any that have the max date of potentially two date values (an older date and a newer date)

Comment: Perhaps: `df %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarise(col2 = first(na.omit(col2)))`?

Comment: Your examples are confusing. What is the condition that must be met? Show your output alongside the code - you noted that you used the "normal distinct functions" but we do not know what those are or how you used them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could group arrange and slice:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  arrange(col2, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

This (for this example!!!) gives the same result using `add_count`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  add_count(col2) %>% 
  filter(n!=1) %>%
  select(-n)
```

```
 col1   col2
  <chr> <int>
1 a         1
2 b         1
3 c         1
4 d         1
```

Comment: I understand the second one here - I think this works for provided simple example but fails with large sets of varying counts. Or at least it works but can get more complicated. 

The 1st seems to have worked - I have to research more on slice/arrange. Thanks a ton

Comment: Yes you are right . The second one is just to use with caveat, but may help in certain situations! I have added a caveat!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(col2) | n() == 1) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   col1   col2
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 a         1
#> 2 b         1
#> 3 c         1
#> 4 d         1
```

Comment: This one almost works. It is removing an extra 6 col1 id's that should still be there post duplicate removal.

Comment: I guess that with my updated solution, that does not occur.